# Get dynamic id value in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I need to get the value of the id = "1" which is dynamic and is immediately after id = "divContenedor".

```html
<html debug="true">
<head>
<script src="chrome-extension://bmagokdooijbeehmkpknfglimnifench/googleChrome.js"/>
<body onload="/*xajax.$('cargando').style.top=document.body.scrollTop+300+'px'; xajax.$('cargando').style.left=document.body.scrollWidth/2-121+'px';*/" onclose="alert('lalala');" style="cursor: default;">
<div id="general" style="text-align: left;">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin-bottom: 8px;">
<div id="notas" class="notas"/>
<div id="divContenedor" class="central">
**<div id="1">**
<div style="padding: 4px 0px; border-top-width: 1px; border-top-style: solid; border-top-color: rgb(181, 209, 221);">
<div class="menuContenedor">
<span style="float: right;">
```

My CasperJS code:

```js
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start('http:\\www.example.es');

casper.then(function() {
  var id = document.getElementById('divContenedor').firstChild
  this.echo(id);
});

casper.run();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CasperJS is built on top of PhantomJS and use its model of the two contexts. Only the page context is able to access the DOM and you can only pass serializable values in and out of it. This is done through [`casper.evaluate()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate):

```
casper.then(function() {
    var id = this.evaluate(function(sel) {
      return document.getElementById(sel).children[0].id;
    }, 'divContenedor');
    this.echo(id);
});
```

The PhantomJS documentation for [`evaluate()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) has an important note:

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the `evaluate` function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> **Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will *not* work!**

---

Other small things:

- `element.firstChild` works on nodes an not just elements. So the first child is probably always a TextNode which doesn't have an id.
- `http:\\www.example.es` is not a valid URL. Use forward slashes: `http://www.example.es/`

Comment: I printed to the console null. I do not understand what the problem is ..:-(

Comment: Don't use `firstChild`, but use `children[0]` instead. I extended my answer.

Comment: :-) Well, it works, could you help me to get the text that appears without labels?
<h5> name_1 </ h5> want to capture this <h5> nombre_2 </ h5> want to capture this.
Thanks again

Comment: I don't see that in your question, so I don't know what you're talking about. Retrieving `element.textContent` actually removes all HTML markup and returns only the text.

Comment: Please, I want to vote for him, tells me that I need 15 reputation